# terraform, using imported resources from a module attempting to delete and recreate

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a terraform script 'script1.tf', which uses some imported azure resources, which I hydrated with import, and this script works fine.

Next I tried to run a module using 'script1' as the source, but the module wants to recreate the imported resources. The imported resources are not managed by our team. I just want to use them without modification.

My question is in regards to using imported resource:
Constraint, some resources are not managed by our team, but we need to reference in .tf file, therefore the import occurring in the directory of the working script.

For example: creating a NIC, using an already created subnet that is imported.

but now from another tf file utilizing a module, using the 'script1' as the source, I want to ignore or not update or create imported resources, but be able to use them when utilizing a module.

In this scenario it doesn't work.

In summary,
A script using imported resources, works fine to create resources dependent on the imported resources.
A module, using the source script, fails because it errors on recreating the externally created resources (of which we don't have rights to modify)

Answer (score 2):

When using 3rd party resources you don't want to import them into resources you define but rather use [data sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html) that you can get information from but you can't modify. If the other team is also using Terraform you may want to look into [remote state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html).